# Can I use the phrase 'sororal twins' to describe a set of female twins?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

*Fraternal twins* is what you call a set of twins who look different, but the word *fraternal* also has the meaning 'of or relating to brothers', and comes from a Latin root meaning 'brother'.

The question is, how do I refer to a set of twins who look different but are both girls? May I use the phrase *sororal twins* to describe them? Or can *fraternal* be used here, too?

Comment: This seems easily answerable by looking up _sororal_ in a dictionary, or even just putting the word into Google, which would give multiple examples of the word being used. Is there any reason you doubt its validity?

Comment: @Heartspring Thanks. I've edited it to describe exactly what prompted my question.

Comment: So ... @Heartspring answered the original question, but the question has now been changed.

Comment: Following your clarification, I've given your question a pretty big edit to make it more clear what you were asking (also cast a reopen vote). Let me know, and feel free to [edit] your question if I've misunderstood it.

Comment: 'Dizygotic (DZ) or fraternal twins (also referred to as "non-identical twins", "dissimilar twins", "biovular twins", and, informally in the case of females, "sororal twins") usually occur when two fertilized eggs are implanted in the uterus wall at the same time.' Source:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin/. This question is GR, easily found, but *sororal twins* is not common (SE, USA).

Comment: In my experience, most people have no idea what a fraternal, maternal, paternal, or even identical twin is. It's a running joke among male-female dizygotic twins--especially the most obviously non-identical--that they are frequently asked "are you identical?" Would you use a different term for male-female twins? What about heteropaternal superfecundation? I think the term "twins" should suffice. Most twins I know would simply prefer to be called, in this case, *sisters*.

Comment: Best answer in such cases is usually to ask them what they prefer to be called.

Comment: 'Fraternal twins' is a fixed expression with a non-default stipulative definition of 'fraternal' if one decides to deconstruct. Wikipedia states that the corresponding expression for two non-identical female twins 'sororal twins' is used but only in informal registers. 'Fraternal twins' may be used as a blanket term for any pair of non-identical twins [[The Oklahoman](https://eu.oklahoman.com/story/lifestyle/2009/02/17/twin-girls-dont-need-new-word/61462002007/)], including girl + boy.

Comment: @jimm101 I'm pretty sure most people know what identical twins are, most probably even know some. The other terms are less common (I've never heard of "paternal" and "maternal"), but I think many know that fraternal means non-identical.

Comment: @Barmar. I agreed until I married my wife, who has a twin brother. People ask if they're identical about 50% of the time they find out she has a twin. Ditto a co-worker, so I started asking around. Strange but true.

Comment: @jimm101 People say stupid things all the time. When they hear someone say they have a twin, it's a habit to ask if they're identical, without the fact that they're opposite sexes sinking in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Informally**, the term "sororal twins" is used:

> To Become a Priest: A Love Storybooks. Den Adler · 2007
>
> Patrick shot her a look. “A sore what?” “Sororal twins. It means
> sisterly, like fraternal means brotherly. It's in the dictionary. I
> looked it up.” “There are no such things as sororal twins,” Patrick
> said. Jessica stuck out her tongue.

> Your Own Neuron: A Tour of Your Psychic Brainbooks. Abhijit Naskar 2015
>
> Figure 3.1 Monozygotic and Dizygotic Embryo Formation Dizygotic or
> non-identical twins (also known as "fraternal twins", "dissimilar
> twins", "biovular twins", and, informally in the case of females,
> "sororal twins") usually occur when ...

**Formally**, it is not:

> Encyclopedia of Genetics, Genomics, Proteomics, and Informatics PAGE
> 714 George P. Rédei · 2008   one or both of the twins are girls (in
> the latter case, the biologically correct usage should be “sororal
> twins” but it is not used).

> Fertility and Pregnancy: An Epidemiologic Perspective - Page 306 Allen
> J. Wilcox · 2010
>
> Tubal pregnancy (see Ectopic) Twins, Dizygous (Fraternal) Two infants
> in the same pregnancy who arise from two separate ova (which raises
> the question of “sororal” twins or “trizygous” triplets, neither of
> which term is used.)